# Create APPX package and DMG package on windows

Tags: electron, windows-store, dmg, appx, makeappx

I've just finish developing an **electron** app for editing PDFs. And I want to create :

1. ***APPX*** Package on Windows Store (for Windows).
2. ***DMG*** Package on App Store (for Mac).

I've searched a lot and didn't find yet how to do it.
Could Anyone help me and tell me how to do it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following tutorial to learn how to create an MSIX for an electron application, using Advanced Installer:

- [MSIX package for electron application](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/electron-msix.html)

Advanced Installer has lightweight support for MacOS, but it can only create ZIP-based packages for Java-based applications. So you can't use it to build an DMG for your electron app.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer*